# How to forward emails to another address only after other rules have filtered

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007

I am using Outlook 2007 and I would like to create a rule that will only forward any email that lands into the inbox and exclude any that are already filtered into other folders via the current rules that are already set up.

I know how to create the rule to forward but I'm not seeing anything that gives the option of only emails that land in the inbox.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set "stop processing more rules" action in your rules that sort messages into folder and place the forwarding rule in the bottom of the list.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow here. I want the other rules processed before forwarding the emails that way everything that is filtered into the other folders will not be send.  will this accomplish that?

Comment: After reading more about the stop processing more rules, I was able to do just as you said and this works great.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the option is in Outlook 2007, but you could make all of the other rules assign a category to the message and then create the forwarding rule and add in "except if it is assigned to any category".

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working.  Perhaps it's because this is a client-only rule and I need it to take affect on the server level?

Comment: Sorry, not too sure what you could do at that point except maybe forward all emails and then create rules on the other recipient to delete unwanted emails.